# When fetching PFObjects using PFQuery it does not returns complete Objects

Tags: parse-platform

When fetching PFObjects using PFQuery it does not returns complete objects. The retuned objects have only few fields. But real objects does have around 12 fields it returns only 7 fields.

Comment: Could you add your code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are fetching the PFObjects it will return the PFObjects in whole. But the issue is that it won't return the fields which does not have the values in it. PFObjects returns all fields which have values in it.